# Fullcalendar - trying to update ending up with duplicate calendars

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I have a single week fullcalendar on a page containing user schedules by name.   I have a text box where a user can enter a username to search by partial stringmatch.  My plan was to grab the val() of the textbox, change the {events:"/myfeed"} and refetchEvents if needed.  Here is what I did:

```
$("#username").on("input", function(){
 // reload calendar with partial string match of textbox
 var username = $("#username").val();  // get the partial username
 var thismorninghash = morninghash;  // make a copy of the main parameter hash

 thismorninghash['events']='/main/feed/user?user=' + username; // change the feed
 $("#calendar-am").fullCalendar(thismorninghash);

});
```

My problem is that I can fetch the new feed but for every character typed, I get a whole new 1 week calendar.   I do not get duplicate events in the calendar (as others ask about) I get a brand new calendar.   If I type "smith" I get the original plus 5 new calendars.   I'm perplexed at this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove existing calendar before load again,

```
$("#calendar-am").fullCalendar("destroy");
```